# What is Code Name Tripoli?

Tags: search, diagnostics, tripoli

In order to log to the ULS using the default `SPDiagnosticsService` you have to provide a registered Area and Category name. If you run this console application code from the [SPDiagnosticsServiceBase.Areas property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spdiagnosticsservicebase.areas.aspx) page on MSDN:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SPDiagnosticsService diagnosticsService = SPDiagnosticsService.Local;
            foreach (SPDiagnosticsArea area in diagnosticsService.Areas)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nArea: {0}", area.Name);

                foreach (SPDiagnosticsCategory category in area.Categories)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Category: {0}", category.Name);
                }
            }
            Console.Write("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

it will enumerate the valid Areas and Categories. In the list of diagnostics information there are a number of curious diagnostic category names including Tripoli (which I assume is an MSFT project code name):

```
Area: SharePoint Foundation Search
...
Category: Tripoli BigTable
Category: Tripoli BitStm
Category: Tripoli Cat
Category: Tripoli Content Index
Category: Tripoli CU
Category: Tripoli Cursor
Category: Tripoli DocSum
Category: Tripoli Exceptions
Category: Tripoli Falloc
Category: Tripoli Filter
Category: Tripoli Filter Registration
Category: Tripoli FilterWids
Category: Tripoli FindFirst
Category: Tripoli Fresh List
Category: Tripoli FSNotify
Category: Tripoli Heap
Category: Tripoli Key Maker
Category: Tripoli KeyList
Category: Tripoli MergeLog
Category: Tripoli Noise
Category: Tripoli Normalize
Category: Tripoli Parse
Category: Tripoli PComp
Category: Tripoli PDir
Category: Tripoli Pending
Category: Tripoli Perf
Category: Tripoli PidTable
Category: Tripoli PropStore
Category: Tripoli PropTime
Category: Tripoli Proxy
Category: Tripoli Query
Category: Tripoli QUtil
Category: Tripoli Range Query
Category: Tripoli Regex
Category: Tripoli Results
Category: Tripoli RowTime
Category: Tripoli SecStore
Category: Tripoli Srch
Category: Tripoli Thesaurus
Category: Tripoli VA
Category: Tripoli WidList
Category: Tripoli Words
Category: Tripoli Workids
Category: Tripoli YACC
Category: TripoliBufferCache
```

What is this? <strike>Is this the FAST integration?</strike> Or just the internal name for the search engine? Or what?

## Edit:

This can't be FAST integration because in the explanation provided in [Guide to walking a SharePoint 2010 Search Query behind the scenes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2012/02/15/guide-to-walking-a-sharepoint-2010-search-query-behind-the-scenes.aspx), which explicitly states: "This scenario is strictly SharePoint 2010 without Fast", the Tripoli code is called with the explanation:

> Here is where Query Processor will start fetching results from the Query Component\s holding the index to retrieve results as well as the Search Property Store Database on the SQL server:
>
> 01/27/2012 09:31:18.02    w3wp.exe (0x1544)    0x1644    SharePoint Server Search    Query Processor    e2pp    Verbose    Entering Split Command Tree parser.                                             [splitter.cxx:184]  d:\office\source\search\native\ytrip\tripoli\icommand\splitter.cxx    599cd6ce-7c0c-44e8-8983-0be66f7176ad
>
> 01/27/2012 09:31:18.43    w3wp.exe (0x1544)    0x1644    SharePoint Server Search    Query Processor    e2ps    Verbose    Tree only had both FT and SQL constraints... split apart.                       [splitter.cxx:230]  d:\office\source\search\native\ytrip\tripoli\icommand\splitter.cxx    599cd6ce-7c0c-44e8-8983-0be66f7176ad

So is Tripoli the data access layer between the search service and SQL? Or is it the query processor?

Comment: That's an interesting question, indeed

Comment: Lately my questions have been fueled by pure curiosity more than anything.

Comment: hmmm, the plot thickens http://webdoc.gwdg.de/ebook/aw/1999/webcrawler/mailing-lists/robots/0804.html

Comment: Wow, that link is from 1996. Nice find!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the link from Derek Gusoff I started searching outside the scope of SharePoint.

I found this CNet article also from 1996: [MS to introduce Tripoli search engine](http://news.cnet.com/MS-to-introduce-Tripoli-search-engine/2100-1023_3-213547.html)

The article explains:

> Microsoft's search engine, code-named Tripoli, is designed to be used by companies for searches of their Web sites, rather than the entire Internet. While the Net sees a proliferation in the number of global search engines, such as Yahoo and Lycos, an increasing number of sites are employing such "off-the-shelf" tools as Tripoli to offer more comprehensive queries or information.

and continues...

> By the end of the second quarter, Microsoft will post a beta version of Tripoli, which was previewed at the company's Professional Developer Conference earlier this year. Developed in-house, the search engine will allow content indexing and full-text retrieval on Web sites, according to the company.

So it appears Tripoli is the internal and/or prior name of the search engine as a whole, and it appears that SharePoint search (or at least a portion of it) is an evolution of this IIS add-on from almost 20 years ago.